# Finding $p$ for geometric distribution

Tags: probability

Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[0, 1]$. Once $U$ is known, additional independent uniform random variables $X1,X2, . . .$ are generated (still on $[0, 1]$) until one gets one that equals or exceeds $U$. Let $N$ be the number of extra variables which are generated, that is, $N$ is the smallest $n$ for which $X_{n} \geq U$.

So it seems like $N \sim geo(p)$, where $p$ is the $P(X_{n} \geq U)$. So to find $p$, I did $1 - P(X_{n} \lt  U)$ which can be calculated by conditioning on $U$.

So $$ P(X_{n} \lt  U)  = \int _{0} ^{1} P(X_{n} \lt u | U = u) P(U = u) du. $$
However, I end up getting $1$. Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. I guess you want to determine the distribution of $N$? Then $N$ has not a $Geo(p)$ distribution, but for the conditional distribution we have $N \ \vert \ U=u \sim Geo(1-u)$. Straight calculations give then for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N=n)= \int_{[0,1]} u^{n-1} (1-u)du =  \frac{u^n}{n}- \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} \bigg\vert_0^1=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}, \qquad n \geq 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh that make sense. If I wanted to find the E(N) do I need to use the Law of Iterated Expectations or can I use the regular expectation formula

Comment: Well, if you really want to compute the expectation of $N$, just apply the regular formular to the determined distribution above (you're gonna find out that the expectation does not exist since the harmonic series does not converge). If you want to find the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E} [N \vert U]$, use that we already know the conditional distribution $N \vert U$.